# sqlalchemy declarative_base() schema_name not working

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I'm creating SQLAlchemy objects for MSSQL via sub-classing declarative_base().
When shifting from in-memory sqlite to production on MSSQL a try and specify the correct MS 'schema' with:

```
create_engine(config.DB, schema_name='myschema', echo=False)
```

however the sql emitted is does not include this schema in the query. Am i doing something wrong?
All is working great with sqlite in-memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

answered by ThiefMaster on freenode #sqlalchemy

if you set the schema directly on the object then it works:

```
__table_args__ = {'schema': 'myschema'}
```